# Apache Drill: How to resolve - RESOURCE ERROR: One or more nodes ran out of memory while executing the query?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, apache-drill

I am using `Apache Drill` version `1.14` on `windows` system and running Drill using the command:

```
sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"
```

I am trying to `execute` a `join query` on two `compressed` and `archived` `CSV` files.

Query:

```
SELECT  *  FROM dfs.`C:\Users\admin\Desktop\DRILL_FILES\csvFileParquet\TBL_MOREDATA-20180924181406.tar.gz` AS Table0 INNER JOIN dfs.`C:\Users\admin\Desktop\DRILL_FILES\csvFileParquet\TBL_MOREDATA1-20180924181406.tar.gz` AS Table1  ON  Table0.columns[0]=Table1.columns[0]
```

But an out of memory, error occurred:

```
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: RESOURCE ERROR: One or more nodes ran out of memory while executing the query. Unable to allocate buffer of size 131072 (rounded from 86104) due to memory limit (630194176). Current allocation: 630108434 Fragment 0:0 [Error Id: 585c0644-5fd5-446e-b9b3-d48e0771eb2a on DESKTOP-SM3E3KM:31010]
```

To resolve the issue, I tried to update `config\drill-env.sh` file but the issue remains the same and it looks like updating the script file does not reflect the changes because I am trying to increase the DIRECT MEMORY beyond the system memory (RAM), every time drill starts up peacefully. Not even complaining that you have exceeded the memory, therefore, it looks like the changes are not reflecting.

```
export DRILLBIT_MAX_PROC_MEM=12G
export DRILL_HEAP=2G
export DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY=10G
```

whereas my system's main memory is only 8 GB.

**Please help me to resolve the out of memory error**. I had even run the below queries, in order to follow the troubleshooting instructions but the issue remains the same.

```
alter session set `planner.enable_hashagg` = false;  
alter session set `planner.enable_hashjoin` = false;
alter session set planner.width.max_per_node=3; 
alter system set planner.width.max_per_query = 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [doc](https://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-plain-text-files/#querying-compressed-files) Drill support only compressed files reading, not archived. You can create a Jira ticket to implement it.
Drill returns unreadable data for the first row in case of archived compressed CSV file reading. So you can use `offset 1`.

Drill leverages the Direct memory for storing batches. So JOIN operations require more direct memory.
Reducing parallelism can lead to less memory consumption:

set `planner.width.max_per_node` (and optionally `planner.width.max_per_query` to 1. 

Disable HashJoin operator usage: `planner.enable_hashjoin`. 

See more in [Drill documentation.](https://drill.apache.org/docs/troubleshooting/#queries-running-out-of-memory)

Also consider enabling `planner.memory.enable_memory_estimation` option.

To verify whether your configs from `drill-env.sh` are applied, run the following query:

```
select * from sys.memory;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Please also let me know that why drill is NOT complaining even if increased the DIRECT MEMORY beyond the system memory (RAM)? Am I updating the right file? In the script, should it be like this- `export DRILLBIT_MAX_PROC_MEM=${DRILLBIT_MAX_PROC_MEM:-"12G"}` OR like this `export DRILLBIT_MAX_PROC_MEM=12G` ?

Comment: I have edited the answer with recommendations. Both configs are valid, but in first case the parameter will be initialized in case of absent this property in the system. Check `select * from sys.memory` to verify